# Concat all parameters and make string in Stored Proc?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have parameters in SP and trying to make them a concat to string

```
@OBID int,
@ODID int,
@EMID int,
@TYPE varchar(20),
@LastModifiedBy int

SET @Strcat = @OBID +','+ @CursorODID +','+@EmpName +','+@TYPE
```

It is giving error.

```
 Error Description: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ',' 
to data type int. 1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Convert all non-string variables to string and then concat...

```
SET @Strcat = Convert(varchar(50), @OBID) +','+ Convert(varchar(50), @CursorODID) +','+@EmpName +','+@TYPE
```

Comment: Don't forget to keep the length of @Strcat to accept all the variables value, other wise you will get the trimed result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert it first to nvarchar/varchar:

```
@OBID int,
@ODID int,
@EMID int,
@TYPE varchar(20),
@LastModifiedBy int

SET @Strcat = CONVERT(nvarchar,@OBID) +','+ CONVERT(nvarchar,@CursorODID) +','+@EmpName +','+@TYPE
```

Regards